# React, show quantity of how many elements match after filtering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this input that filters through a state and shows only the elements that match after typing something, as an extra bonus I need to show the quantity of how many items match.

For example:

If I type "react" only the elements with the react word in it will be shown so the render should show something like this.

```
There are 2 enterprises that have what you need
```

My code:

```
const searchingFor = (term) => {
    return (x) => {
        return x.tecnologia.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()) || !term;
    }
}


class FilterClass extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            empresas: [
                {
                    empresa: "Daniel",
                    tecnologia: "React",
                    clientes: ["sodimac", "ripley", "paris"],
                    experiencia: "5 años",
                    id: 1

                },
                {
                    empresa: "Juan",
                    tecnologia: "React",
                    clientes: ["Falabella", "ripley", "ikea"],
                    experiencia: "3 años",
                    id: 2

                },
                {
                    empresa: "David",
                    tecnologia: "Angular",
                    clientes: ["Falabella", "ripley", "ikea"],
                    experiencia: "3 años",
                    id: 2

                },
                {
                    empresa: "Carlos",
                    tecnologia: "Vue",
                    clientes: ["Copec", "Wallmark", "Unimark"],
                    experiencia: "6 años",
                    id: 3

                }
            ],
            term: ''
        }

        this.searchHandler = this.searchHandler.bind(this);

    }

    searchHandler(event) {
        this.setState({ term: event.target.value })
    }

    render() {

        const {term, empresas} = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <form className="container--flex-center">
                    <input type="text" onChange={this.searchHandler} value={term} />
                </form>
                {empresas.filter(searchingFor(term)).map(item =>
                    <FilterComponent
                        empresa={item.empresa}
                        tecnologia={item.tecnologia}
                        clientes={item.clientes}
                        experiencia={item.experiencia}
                        key={item.id}
                    />
                )}

            </div>
        )
    }


}

export default FilterClass;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I do not know where this bonus message should appear, so excuse me if it is not the correct answer.

Well I inserted the message just below the map and then put a filter in the matrix that returns the size as a condition to render the bonus message.

```
{empresas.filter(element => element.tecnologia === term).length > 0 &&
    <div>
        here are {empresas.filter(element => element.tecnologia === term).length} enterprises that have what you need
    </div>
}
```

> Result

```
render() {

    const {term, empresas} = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <form className="container--flex-center">
                <input type="text" onChange={this.searchHandler} value={term} />
            </form>
            {empresas.filter(element => element.tecnologia === term).map(item =>
                <FilterComponent
                    empresa={item.empresa}
                    tecnologia={item.tecnologia}
                    clientes={item.clientes}
                    experiencia={item.experiencia}
                    key={item.id}
                />
            )}
            {empresas.filter(element => element.tecnologia === term).length > 0 &&
                <div>There are {empresas.filter(element => element.tecnologia === term).length} enterprises that have what you need</div>
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: {empresas.filter(element => element.tecnologia === term).length > 0 &&
    <div>
        here are {empresas.filter(element => element.tecnologia === term).length} enterprises that have what you need
    </div>
}

Works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the count of the matched results you can do a trick like this. First Filter you empresas array with your condition then map it.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const searchingFor = term => {
  return x => {
    return x.tecnologia.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()) || !term;
  };
};

class FilterClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      empresas: [
        {
          empresa: "Daniel",
          tecnologia: "React",
          clientes: ["sodimac", "ripley", "paris"],
          experiencia: "5 años",
          id: 1
        },
        {
          empresa: "Juan",
          tecnologia: "React",
          clientes: ["Falabella", "ripley", "ikea"],
          experiencia: "3 años",
          id: 2
        },
        {
          empresa: "David",
          tecnologia: "Angular",
          clientes: ["Falabella", "ripley", "ikea"],
          experiencia: "3 años",
          id: 3
        },
        {
          empresa: "Carlos",
          tecnologia: "Vue",
          clientes: ["Copec", "Wallmark", "Unimark"],
          experiencia: "6 años",
          id: 4
        }
      ],
      term: "",
      matchedcount: 0
    };

    this.searchHandler = this.searchHandler.bind(this);
    this.contnmap = this.contnmap.bind(this);
  }

  searchHandler(event) {
    this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
  }

  contnmap(term, empresas) {
    let matchedcount = empresas.filter(searchingFor(term));
    let count = Object.keys(matchedcount).length;
    return [
      matchedcount.map(item => (
      <FilterComponent
                    empresa={item.empresa}
                    tecnologia={item.tecnologia}
                    clientes={item.clientes}
                    experiencia={item.experiencia}
                    key={item.id}
                />
      )),
      count
    ];
  }

  render() {
    const { term, empresas } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.searchHandler} value={term} />

        {this.contnmap(term, empresas)[0]}
        <div>count:{this.contnmap(term, empresas)[1]}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FilterClass;
```

Here the `contnmap()` function returns an array where the 1st element will be the set of react elements and the next is the count.

Answer (score 0):

You can just save the result of the filter (and render them later) and use `.length` to get the count:

```
render() {
    const {term, empresas} = this.state;
    const termItems = empresas.filter(searchingFor(term))

    return (
        <div>
            <form className="container--flex-center">
                <input type="text" onChange={this.searchHandler} value={term} />
            </form>
            <p>There are {termItems.length} enterprises that have what you need</p>
            {termItems.map(item =>
                <FilterComponent
                    empresa={item.empresa}
                    tecnologia={item.tecnologia}
                    clientes={item.clientes}
                    experiencia={item.experiencia}
                    key={item.id}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

This way, you don't have to filter twice and just use a variable. Simple, clean, and reusable.